# Inverses of circulant matrices with integer entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C_n(\mathbb{Z})$ be the set of circulant matrices of order $n$ with integer coefficients. Let $C(a_0,...,a_{n-1})$ denote the circulant matrix whose first line equals $(a_0,...,a_{n-1})$. Let $G$ be the set of matrices $M$ in  $C_n(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $M$ is invertible and $M^{-1}$ is in $C_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

$G$ is a group because $C_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is stable under multiplication. Also, if $M \in G$ then clearly $\det M=\pm 1$  because $\det M$ is an integer dividing $1$.

**I'm pretty sure the reverse implication is also true, i.e: $M \in C_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and  $\det M=\pm 1$ then $M \in G$.**

Indeed, from $M (^tCom(M))=(\det M )I_n$ we have for $M$ satisfying $M \in C_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and  $\det M=\pm 1$ that $M^{-1} \in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Also, if $A \in C_n(\mathbb{Z})$ then $^tA \in C_n(\mathbb{Z})$, so to show that $M^{-1} \in C_n(\mathbb{Z})$ it suffices to show that $Com(M) \in C_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

**Is there an easy way to show that the comatrix of a circulant matrix is circulant?**

Finally, I found that for $n=2,3,4$ that $G$ is finite and in particular it is isomorphic to $Z/nZ \times Z/2Z$, and I wonder if this holds in general. The way I found this was by calculating the determinant of $C(a_0,...,a_{n-1})$ in terms of $a_0,...,a_{n-1}$, so we get a product of integer terms equal to $\pm 1$. This forces all of $a_0,...,a_{n-1}$ to be equal to zero except for one $a_i$ for which we have $a_i= \pm 1$.

Hence if $e_i$ denotes the vector $(0,...1,...0)$ where $1$ is in position $i$ then $G=\{C(\pm e_1),..., C(\pm e_{n-1})\}=\{ \pm J^0,..., \pm J^{n-1} \}$ where $J$ is the matrix of order $n$ such that $J_{i,j}=0$ for all $(i,j)$ except if $j=i+1$ or $i=0,j=n$. (it is well known that every circulant matrix is a polynomial in $J$). The conclusion is immediate.

**Thus is it true that $G$ is isomorphic to $Z/nZ \times Z/2Z$ for all $n$?**

**Edit:**

Concerning the second question, there is a work-around. If $A$ is circulant and inversible, then let $A=P(J)$ for some polynomial $P$. Since $J^n=I_n$, $J$ is diagonalisable and the eigenvectors are $w^0,..w^{n-1}$ for $w$ a primitive nth root of unity. Hence $A$ is similar to the diagonal matrice $D$ with $D_{i,i}=P(w^i)$. Thus $det A =P(w^0)...P(w^{n-1})$. Since $A$ is inversible, $P$ is thus relatively prime with $x^n-1$, thus by Bezout's theorem, there exist polynomials $U$ and $V$ such that $UP+V(x^n-1)=1$. Evaluating in $J$ we get $U(J)A=I$ Hence the inverse of $A$ is a polynomial in $J$, and thus circulant.

Answer (score 0):

How about $n=5$ and $(1,-1,0,0,-1)$?

That is the circulant matrix
$$\pmatrix{1&-1&0&0&-1\\-1&1&-1&0&0\\
0&-1&1&-1&0\\0&0&-1&1&-1\\-1&0&0&-1&1}.$$

Comment: Sharke the Unknown: what about it? Is this supposed to be a counterexample to something?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou It's a **matrix**. It's a circulant matrix. I'm pretty sure that its inverse is a circulant matrix, with integer entries and with infinite order.

Comment: infinite order? its of order 5. order=size of matrix.

Comment: ah. you mean order in the group sense. interesting. how did you find it so quickly?